# Excel file generated by table2excel jQuery plugin throws error when opened

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, excel

I have a HTML table that I want to export to Excel using the [table2excel](http://www.jqueryscript.net/table/Export-Html-Table-To-Excel-Spreadsheet-using-jQuery-table2excel.html) plugin. Unfortunately when I download it, the generated Excel file has an error. How can I fix that?

I have created a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t8tegrad/2/).

Basically to call the plugin you just need to do this:

```
$("#downloadIntermidiate").click(function(){

                        $("#intermediateTable").table2excel({
                              exclude: ".noExl",
                        name: "Excel Document intermediateTable"
                        }); 

                         });
```

Here `#intermediateTable` is the id of the table that has to be printed.

Comment: If I change the file name from `.xlsx` to `.xls` I get a warning message, but the file opens and looks OK.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You fiddle works Fine, Just Changed .xlsx to .xls , it exports

```
function getFileName(settings) {
    return ( settings.filename ? settings.filename : "table2excel") + ".xls";
 }
```

Check this fiddle-> https://jsfiddle.net/t8tegrad/8/

Comment: I get a warning message saying that the file extension do not match the content when I open the file downloaded from the fiddle. It opens and looks OK, though.

Comment: @Anirudh Well I am very new to this plugin , I have been using PHP2Excel till now , But I am gonna except your answer , Feel free to update it in case you find out the problem .about warning .

Comment: yea, because the format is different. if u click ok, it opens because u have called.xls whcih is an excel format.

Comment: .xlsx format can be used if u are using excel version above 2007.

Comment: When we open the excel file it through error of corrupt file and extension error any solution for this?