# Excel file can not normally open

Tags: javascript, jquery, excel

My Excel file generated by the table2excel jQuery plugin will not open properly, and will throw **XXXX.xls file format; the extension doesn't match.**
and I think this file is a text file, not a real binary excel file.
[image: error]

**Js:**

```
e.uri = "data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,";
link = e.uri + e.base64(e.format(fullTemplate, e.ctx));
a = document.createElement("a");
a.download = getFileName(e.settings);
a.href = link;

document.body.appendChild(a);

a.click();

document.body.removeChild(a);
```

Visit my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t8tegrad/8/) to see my code!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Excel file generated by table2excel jQuery plugin throws error when opened](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33031702/excel-file-generated-by-table2excel-jquery-plugin-throws-error-when-opened)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50819212/414744
This might help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I happened across this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33031702/excel-file-generated-by-table2excel-jquery-plugin-throws-error-when-opened?rq=1), and it appears you are using the answer's [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t8tegrad/8/). The reason it pops up the warning is because it is formated in `.xlsx` and has an extension of `.xls`, so it thinks it could be a virus. To solve this all you have to do is use the other [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t8tegrad/2/), and have a version of Excel above 2007, as the other jsfiddle doesn't convert the file format, and Excel above 2007 can open those files.

Comment: Thanks for answering, I used the excel2016, when I used your method, there will be the following error: excel cannot open the file xxx.xlsx' because the file format is not valid error

Comment: I answered because I thought you were using a different version, but it works just fine for me if I click yes in 2010.

Comment: Anyway, thank you,I have resolved that my previous solution is not appropriate, because he is the text format forced into a .xls or .xlsx suffix, and excel is binary

Comment: Sorry I don't get what you mean, did I help or not? Probably best to not have too many comments, but I need the clarification.

Comment: In simple terms, the table2excel jQuery plugin can not be used to get a real excel file.This file is not a real binary file.I'm sorry for my bad English.