# Jquery Table2Excel module: Works but Excel throws error

Tags: jquery, excel

I'm exporting some tabledata to Excel using the Jquery module Table2Excel. It works fine but Excel throws the following error when opening.

[image]

After closing the message box the data shows up. There is an accepted answer to this issue here: [Excel Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33031702/excel-file-generated-by-table2excel-jquery-plugin-throws-error-when-opened) However, it does not fix the problem.

Here is the function:

```
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/unconditional/jquery-table2excel/master/src/jquery.table2excel.js"></script>
<script>
  jQuery(document).ready(function() {    
  $('#exportNow').on('click', function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      ResultsToTable();
  });      
  function ResultsToTable(){    
      $("#tabledata").table2excel({
          exclude: ".noExl", //this class data should not be excluded in excel
          filename: "SummaryReport"
      });
  }
   });
</script>
```

Comment: The error from the other post was something else. Your error seems to be related to the file type. Have you tried to configure your code to safe the file with  another extension?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Excel file generated by table2excel jQuery plugin throws error when opened](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33031702/excel-file-generated-by-table2excel-jquery-plugin-throws-error-when-opened)

Comment: @TheFool Sorry that was the link that I intended to include in my original posting. I edited that. That solution still throws the error.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that for some reason, your file got hte name **"SummaryReport.xlsx-1.xls"**
The name of your file must be extended with **.xls** as in the other So-Post you cited

```
filename: "SummaryReport.xls"
```